# How to run a specific DOS Command

Tags: c#

I tried various methods possible to run this specific DOS command through C#. I do not want to use a batch file. Whatever I try, it keeps taking only first word from Printer name and not the entire name, in this case, it says Printer POS is not connected instead of saying Printer POS Lexmark is not connected. What could the error be? Thanks guys!

The DOS command is:

```
rundll32 printui, PrintUIEntry /o /n "POS Lexmark"
```

My code is as follows:

```
string command = string.Format("/c rundll32 printui, PrintUIEntry /o /n" + " POS Lexmark"); 
ProcessStartInfo cmdsi = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe");
cmdsi.Arguments = command;
cmdsi.CreateNoWindow = false;
Process cmd = Process.Start(cmdsi);
```

Comment: That's not DOS. It's not even console or cmd.exe. It's a Win32 process. There is no DOS on todays Windows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You forgot to include the quotes around POS Lexmark:

```
string command = string.Format("/c rundll32 printui, PrintUIEntry /o /n" + "\" POS Lexmark\"");
```

Comment: +1 because you're right, and this is a good answer as it stands, but this would be a ***better*** answer if you explained why that matters, in case the OP doesn't understand.  ;-)

Comment: All right David, I'll explain - the command parser normally delimits arguments with spaces, so the program was taking the argument after the /n to be "POS", not "POS Lexmark", and making the "Lexmark" a separate argument, which it probably ignored. But you can override this behavior by adding quotes around arguments - commonly used when passing files in "Program Files" or "Documents and Settings" to a command line program. As for the backslash before the quotes, this is needed to escape the quotes so they don't prematurely terminate the string in the C# code.